# Wordpress API without installation

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to use the wordpress API to retrieve recent blog posts from a wordpress blog, and display them on a **non**-wordpress site.

I have read a bunch of tutorials and the documentation on implementing the API, all of which state that you must install wordpress on your server in order to use the API.

Is this definitely the only use case? Is there an implementation I can use which does not require us to install wordpress on the server?

All I want to do is retrieve recent posts and display them in a list which will link out to the actual wordpress blog.

Comment: @KenWhite Because that question and answers are nothing about using the wordpress API. The wordpress API was released in 2016.

Comment: @KenWhite However I will still have a look at this implementation - I had not seen this link previously.

Comment: What do you mean by the WordPress API? If you are referring to the REST API the REST client only needs to send/receive HTTP requests.

Comment: Yes the REST API @user8262086. Well that's what I assumed as well until I read.... https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/using-wordpress-rest-api/ ,   http://v2.wp-api.org/ , https://www.sitepoint.com/wp-api/ ..... Which all say you have to install wordpress in order to use the API....?

Comment: I don't have time to read those articles. I use a JavaScript client to access the REST API. You can also run curl commands to access the API. The client does not need anything from WordPress although WordPress has some client libraries for some languages which you may not need depending on what you are trying to do.

Comment: Suggest you read http://v2.wp-api.org/

Comment: @user8262086 If you have time, I would be very interested to see an answer from you with a basic use case with your javascript API calls.

Comment: My JavaScript is actually quite complex since I use custom post types. You should use the command line app curl to send HTTP request to quickly understand how REST servers work.

Comment: Thanks for your time @user8262086

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The folks commenting are confused by your statement, because they all assume (as highly technical individuals do), you're referring to a self-hosted WordPress.

No.  You do **NOT** have to have a WordPress install to use the WordPress**.COM** API.

Example:
https://public-api.wordpress.com/wp/v2

Documentation:
https://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/

Good luck!